# Run thread only for one minute in java

Tags: java, concurrency

What the best practice to run thread only for some period?
I can easily check curentTime and close the thread after in worked for some time, but I think it's not the right way.

Comment: Something like that. `public void run() {   
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while(System.currentTimeMillis()-start<60000) {
                  ....
  }      
 }`

Comment: Give the running code a volatile boolean flag, say called `terminate`, plus getters and setters -- `setTerminate(boolean terminate)` and `isTerminate()`, and check the state of this variable in the running thread, stopping it if true. Then use a [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) object to help decide when to stop your running thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 for the fine proposal, but you must agree that's quite a bit more work than OP's initial suggestion :) The advantage is a nice separation of the actual condition that causes the thread to stop. But given the exact requirement from the question, I can't say there's anything wrong with the simple approach.

Comment: It is more work, but (probably) a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve, but generally speaking the approach you mentioned with measuring the time from the start is not that wrong.

Comment: I just want to spam my mq for one minute in several threads. I never worked with concurrent package yet, so I thought that java has some special staff for this task, something like sheduler. But I like @HovercraftFullOfEels solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would code it like this:

```
private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private final Thread target;
    public MyTimerTask(Thread target) { this.target = target; }
    public void run() {
        target.interrupt();
    }
}

public void run() {
    Thread final theThread = Thread.currentThread();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    try {
         timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(theThread), 60000});
         while(!theThread.interrupted()) {
             ....
         }
    } finally {
         timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

... which is Hovercraft described, except using interrupt instead of an ad-hoc flag.  Using interrupts has the advantage that some I/O calls are unblocked by an interrupt, and some libraries will respect it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised (and deeply disappointed) that no one has mentioned the [Executors framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). It has usurped the Timer framework (or at least the `java.util.Timer` class) as the "goto" for scheduled tasks.

For instance,

```
// Start thread
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try{
                // do stuff
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
});
t.start();

// Schedule task to terminate thread in 1 minute
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        t.interrupt();
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```